# How can I programmatically override a browser's user agent?

Tags: iframe, cross-browser, user-agent

Say I have an `<iframe>` on my webpage. How can I make this iframe appear as an iPhone, for example, by overriding the default user agent for the browser and operating system? Is this effect possible without installing extensions or requiring user interaction?

I know how to toggle this override through Chrome's developer tools (thanks to this tutorial http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2011/12/changing-user-agent-new-google-chrome.html) though I am looking for a programatic and cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to programmatically pull pages from the internet, your best bet would be to use something like `wget` or `curl (libcurl)`.  Chrome isn't really "programmable" unless you are writing an extension for it.

Comment: I think you're right. I want to, for instance, be able to display the mobile version of some site within my page. Is there an affective way to submit such a request – with any proper headers to specify the user agent – using Javascript?

Comment: If you have a webserver which is serving up the files, you can use libcurl or even php to set the user-agent and other headers, that will let your webserver to fetch the mobile version of another site.  Once you get the contents, you can relay the mobile page to your user